# Posso postar respostas do SO no meu blog?

Tags: debate

Seguinte, tenho um blog e gostaria de postar as respostas do S.O.

Por exemplo [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join) pergunta, a resposta é excelente, gostaria de coloca no meu blog.

Agora as dúvidas:

Posso postar o conteúdo(citando a fonte)? ou preciso pedir autorização?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: [Referência a respostas no SO-pt em perguntas feitas no SO-en](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2052/3117) Em resumo: `Se quer saber se pode usar as postagens existentes aqui como fonte em outras postagens em outros sites, entre eles o SOen, pode, desde que indique a fonte conforme a indicação legal no site que usa a licença de conteúdo Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Sim**, você pode colocar no seu blog desde que haja um link direto para a postagem original.

Se você olhar no rodapé desta página verá o seguinte trecho:

> contribuições de usuários com licença de cc by-sa 3.0 com [atribuição necessária](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

Se você clicar no [link de "atribuição necessário"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) verá uma postagem do blog do Stack Overflow dizendo que o conteúdo pode ser compartilhado e alterado, porém mencionando e linkando a fonte.